# How to change the setting so there is no post on home page

Tags: posts, options

How do I set "Blog pages show at most 'Variable' posts" (under setting > reading) to  0 it isn't letting me. So what file do I need to edit so the value is 0?

Comment: I Have a plugin that show top 15 recent post, and I going to modified it in staid of it taking you to a new page, A new sub window will appear in said of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the homepage to a static page (and have no content).

Create a new page, then:

Appearance -> Customise -> Static Front Page tab

And select 'A static page' and then select your new page.

If you set 0 for the value you mentioned above, none of your blog pages will show any content.

Comment: Yea I want have none of your blog pages will show any content! Yea I can I do it!

Comment: And I don't want to see the posts on the home page. and I a spacted page for bloging.

Comment: Using pages, you won't see any of the posts appearing unless you add a loop.

Comment: Doesn't work it shows the title of the page and A edit bottom!

Comment: Edit only appears for you (logged in users who can edit the page), and it will always show the title of the page unless you edit the template in the php. I'm not sure what you are wanting to do, can you show a screenshot?

Comment: Sure I am using the Gantry framework with buddypress

Comment: http://imgur.com/DvsUfvh Here is the screenshot.  Note I did add text in with using pinta!

Comment: It looks as if you might need to create a child theme and edit the theme files. Codex: [Child Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)